# create HDLC interface in linux using serial port

Tags: raspberrypi, tty, interface, serial-port, scapy

I have modified MAX485 board (to work in sniff mod I deleted a terminator resistor) connected to Arduino. This Arduino connected to raspberry pi via USB. I probated this on Modbus/RS485 using IOninja and it works well. Also, I can read serial port bytes flow using pyserial library.

Now I need to listen to TLS/HDLC/RS485. Can you please advice some software that can represent byte flow with this stack of protocols in human-readable form?

The best way is to advise some software that uses serial port data as input like '/dev/ttyUSB0', and produce Linux interface like wlan0 or eth0 to work with it in scapy or Wireshark.